# Error: write EPIPE when trying to upload file to FTP using gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, ftp, gulp, vinyl-ftp

I've got a task to deploy some stylesheets out to a server using FTP and about 80% of the time I get this error,

```
Error: write EPIPE
  at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
  at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:880:14)
```

I'm using [vinyl-ftp](https://github.com/morris/vinyl-ftp) to upload the file as seen in the code here,

```
var conn = ftp.create({
    host: 'host',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    parallel: 10,
    idleTimeout: 10000,
    reload: true,
    secure: true,
    secureOptions: {rejectUnauthorized: false},
    log: gutil.log
});

// What files to transfer over (can be used in case there are more files to be uploaded in the future)
var globs = [
    localDir + '/' + jobName + 'Default.css'
];

gutil.log("Local File: " + globs[0]);

var remoteDir = '/' + environment + '/css/' + clientName + '/' + jobName;

gutil.log("Remote Dir: " + remoteDir);

return gulp.src(globs, {buffer: false}).pipe(conn.dest(remoteDir));
```

The server that I'm uploading to is using FTP-SSL (Explicit AUTH TLS). I'm not sure if that's what's causing the issue but I've tried catching the error and adding an onerror event to process.stdout but none of them work. When the error does trip it uploads an empty file to my server.

It'd be great to find a solution to this or better yet a different FTP package.

**Edit 1:** I'm on Windows.

Comment: Did you try parallel: 3 or something less than 10 to see if it helps?  And conn.newer just to avoid unnecessary uploads?  Might help performance a bit.  I use vinyl-ftp and never get this error and I typically transfer up to 60 files at a time.

Comment: I had such an error when the server was full and there was no place to write files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally just said screw it and changed what module I was using. [node-ftp](https://github.com/mscdex/node-ftp) only throws the EPIPE error about 5% of the time compared to the original 80%. You can also catch the error which is useful because I catch it and try to upload the file again.